# How to format ten thousands (만/万)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I know you can format thousands and millions by using a comma in the custom number format. However, I would like to format by ten thousand (man/wan in Asian counting system). For example `10,000,000` => `1000만` or `1000万`. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 5):

I have two solutions, and both aren't great. The first problem is that Google Sheet has no support for that counting system. It can only shorten a number by thousands, as fractions, or as scientific notation.

---

**First solution** - We can take advantage of the `%` since it expands the value by 100. We use the `,` (comma) to shorten the number to the millions and add on the `%`, giving us this: `0,,"万"%`. This works, but it does have the unfortunate side effect of the value becoming a percentage, which probably won't affect calculations, and including a percentage in the cell. I could not figure out how to hide it.

**Second Soluion** - We use a separate columnto display the wan. Multiply the value by 100 and using the format `0,,"万"`, we display the correct value BUT the underlying value is incorrect. I think it might actually be better to simply format it into a string using a formula such as `=CONCAT(FLOOR(A1/10000),"万")` just so that no mistakes can be made further along the line.

---

All of this of course does not account for 亿 and it's Korean variant (sorry, I don't know much about Korean). Maybe in the future Google will add a way to shrink numbers with more control. But for now, these are what I came up with. Maybe someone else will have a much more fitting solution.

[Read more about number formats here.](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#about_date_time_values)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i got a solution which is a quick fix, can try this can try
0"."0,"万"

Comment: Your answer could be improved if you [edited it](/edit) it to note the relevant implications of this approach. For example, **`1.`** doesn't change the underlying number which may be useful for calculations. **`2.`** Only displays down to the thousands digit therefore the number **`499`** would be displayed as any of the following depending on the number of decimal places shown: **`0.0万`** or **`0.0.5万`** or **`0.0.50万`** or **`0.0.499万`**.